# Spring microservice on docker jdk alpine 8 with BusyBox message

Tags: java, linux, docker, alpine-linux, busybox

I tried to run Spring Cloud microservice on jdk alpine image of docker, but during run of two containers I received the following message:

```
licensingservice_1       | BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.
licensingservice_1       |
licensingservice_1       | Usage: basename FILE [SUFFIX]
licensingservice_1       |
licensingservice_1       | Strip directory path and .SUFFIX from FILE
licensingservice_1       | usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
licensingservice_1       |        [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
licensingservice_1       |        [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
licensingservice_1       |        [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
```

Here is a docker file and run.sh file that are used to build image.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/licensingservice
ADD @project.build.finalName@.jar /usr/local/licensingservice/
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
getPort() {
    echo $1 | cut -d : -f 3 | xargs basename
}

echo "********************************************************"
echo "Waiting for the eureka server to start on port $(getPort $EUREKASERVER_PORT)"
echo "********************************************************"
while ! `nc -z eurekaserver  $(getPort $EUREKASERVER_PORT)`; do sleep 3; done
echo "******* Eureka Server has started"


echo "********************************************************"
echo "Waiting for the configuration server to start on port $(getPort $CONFIGSERVER_PORT)"
echo "********************************************************"
while ! `nc -z configserver $(getPort $CONFIGSERVER_PORT)`; do sleep 3; done
echo "*******  Configuration Server has started"


echo "********************************************************"
echo "Waiting for the kafka server to start on port  $(getPort $KAFKASERVER_PORT)"
echo "********************************************************"
while ! `nc -z kafkaserver  $(getPort $KAFKASERVER_PORT)`; do sleep 10; done
echo "******* Kafka Server has started"

echo "********************************************************"
echo "Starting License Server with Configuration Service via Eureka :  $EUREKASERVER_URI:$SERVER_PORT"
echo "Using Kafka Server: $KAFKASERVER_URI"
echo "Using ZK    Server: $ZKSERVER_URI"
echo "USing Profile: $PROFILE"
echo "********************************************************"
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$SERVER_PORT   \
     -Deureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=$EUREKASERVER_URI             \
     -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=$CONFIGSERVER_URI                          \
     -Dspring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=$KAFKASERVER_URI          \
     -Dspring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=$ZKSERVER_URI             \
     -Dsecurity.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=$AUTHSERVER_URI               \
     -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE -jar /usr/local/licensingservice/@project.build.finalName@.jar
```

I've built the image with `mvn clean package docker:build` command with spotify docker plugin 1.2.0

Comment: What sets the variables like `$EUREKASERVER_PORT`?  I can see this error occurring if those variables are empty.

Comment: @DavidMaze I use docker-compose to pass environment parameters, looks like I omitted a few of them and this weird error came. Thanks for help!